# Using STL containers with exception handling in low memory situation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

I am using STL containers in my code (being developed in C++ using Visual Studio 2010)
I have never used exception handling with STL containers before. Since STL containers throw `bad_alloc` exception, I plan to use like in **sample code** shown below. Let's assume `function()` gets called in low memory situation.

Now, I am not sure if it is full proof code OR do I need to do any additional cleanup activity.

```
class MyClass
{
    std::vector<int>* integer_vector; 
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
            std::string message;
            message += "my message"; // bad_alloc could be thrown from here

            integer_vector = new std::vector<int>; // bad_alloc could be thrown from here
        }   
};

void function()
{
    try
    {
        MyClass* myclass_ptr;
        myclass_ptr = new (std::nothrow) MyClass;
        if (myclass_ptr==NULL)
        {
            // ANY CLEANUP NEEDED HERE ?
            return;
        }

        std::map<int, char> myintcharmap; // bad_alloc could be thrown from here
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // ANY CLEANUP NEEDED HERE ?
        return;
    }
}
```

Please can someone have a look and help.

Comment: Are you asking whether your strategy for handling exceptions is correct, or whether your code could leak memory that it is allocating?

Comment: @MichaelUrman: In fact both. But I am more concerned about whether this code could have any memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main potential leaks in the code you show. Both of which arguably stem from using raw pointers. You should prefer using `std::unique_ptr` (if you have C++11) or other similar "smart" pointers to indicate ownership, and for exception safety in general. Modern guidance is to avoid almost all usage of `new` or `delete`; when they cannot be avoided, they need to be paired. Note that your code has two calls to `new` but none to `delete`.

Inside `function`, the core problem is you could fully allocate data "owned" by `myclass_ptr`, cause an exception in later allocations, and then not be able to clean it up as `myclass_ptr` is no longer in scope.

Let's say you fixed that so it cleaned up the `MyClass` instance if an exception occurred after its creation. Your code would still leak because inside `MyClass` there's currently a similar problem with `integer_vector`. Although you could follow the rule of three and write a destructor to handle this case, it's probably easier to use a smart pointer here as well.

Exception handling is much bigger, much more opinionated topic. I'll leave it with the summary that it's typically bad to catch exceptions and squash them (usually that's only legit in an outer loop of a program that needs specific kinds of stability). It's also typically bad to catch exceptions in a scope so narrow that you don't know how to handle them. (For example, how would `function` decide whether to try again, give up, or use another approach? Its caller, or the caller further on up the chain, may have more information and be in a better place to handle this.)

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. I was just experimenting around. Let's assume I've placed `delete` calls in the same functions just after new. My core point was, **can we be assured that handling bad_alloc exception by STL would make our application leak proof?**

Comment: @Andrew I have the strong feeling you're trying to answer a different question than the one you're asking. If you're asking if the memory for the object is cleaned up when its constructor throw an exception, the answer is yes **if** the object is properly written; using `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of raw pointer members helps with this, as there are fewer partially constructed states. If you're asking if the only exception the code you show might throw is `bad_alloc`, then I'm unclear what the connection is to memory leaks.

Comment: I guess you answered me here. If I use smart pointers, in the code above (and `delete` objects as I mentioned) I can be assured it won't have memory leaks (whenever STL throws `bad_alloc`)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you should not deal with **bad_alloc exceptions**. Your `try/catch` should be removed, as well as `if (myclass_ptr==NULL)`.

Ask yourself : if the process memory is exhausted, what could I possibly do ? Best thing you can hope is to log something, clean up / free the system resources, and let the program terminates. This is the only right thing to do.

You can do this by setting the new_handler (with set_new_handler). It will be called by the new operator if memory allocation failed.

```
std::set_new_handler(my_handler); // do your cleanup in 'my_handler'
```

Comment: Thanks for info on set_new_handler. I didn't know this.

Comment: If I am not wrong, bad_alloc is bound to happen, let's say when there are other memory consuming applications running on the same system and those leave very less amount of physical memory for our app. Or may be that, memory is fragmented. So OS can deny allocation request despite _we see enough free memory_. In such scenario, quitting application is only way you think?